# what is the maximum number of faces with n vertex in planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, planar-graphs

what is the maximum number of faces with n vertex in planar graphs?

v=number of vertices

f= number of faces

for example if v=3 -> max(f)=2

v=4 -> max(f)=4 (a triangle with a point in inner face of it , connected to the three vertex)

v=6-> max(f)=8

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangulatedGraph.html (these are the maximal planar graphs).

Comment: i need a formula for any given n, number of vertices,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula) tells you $v-e+f=2\rightarrow f=e+2-v$.

Using your variables a planar graph with $m$ edges and $n$ vertices has $m+2-n$ faces. Also see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124116/maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-planar-graph) for the maximum value for a given $n$ and unrestricted $m$.

---

For a given $n$ suppose we have a graph which has a face that is not a triangle. Then we can divide that face into two other faces, adding more faces. Therefore the planar graph with the most faces is made up of triangles only.since every triangle has 3 edges and every edge belongs to two triangles we get $3f=2e$ or $e=\frac{3f}{2}$. So $v-\frac{3f}{2}+f=2\rightarrow f=2v-4$

Comment: I have only the number of vertices...

Comment: So if you get n vertices the maximum faces is 2n-4.

Comment: ok thanks, i find out

Comment: This formula only works on connected graphs, right? (from Euler's formula) Worth pointing this out.

Comment: sure, although the inequality also holds for disconnected graphs, although it can be reformulated and be put in terms of the number of components

Comment: "every edge belongs to two triangles" - this is not true for outer edges (the outer face is not a triangle)

Comment: Yes it is, every face must be a triangle.